# Recognize character set (php): ?É¬´

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am confronted with a database that contains codes like: ?É¬´ (which should be: ë). I can't find out which character set has been used. I would like everything be UTF8, so I need to convert these codes. I found php functions that converts character sets, but everything I have tried (mb_detect_encoding, iconv, utf8_decode, etc.) does not convert ?É¬´ to ë. The first problem is that I can't find out which character set is used. The second problem is how to convert that character set to UTF8.

Comment: How do you know that it should be "ë"? Other characters of the string are fine? Do you have any information where the string comes from? Which code has entered the data into the database for example? And when you see the string as `?É¬´` which encoding is used to display the string?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in php? You might have a UTF-8 string in php but be saving it in a latin1 table.

Comment: Have you tried converting from windows-1250 to utf-8? `iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $string);`

Comment: It could be double conversion. Have You set connection to database to UTF-8?

Comment: I know it should be ë because of the context, the word should be: cliënten (which is Dutch for clients). Other special characters give similar problems. The collation of the table is latin1_swedish_ci. The connection is utf8_general_ci.
Yes, tried: iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $string); but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Which script put the data into the column? Was it using utf8 for the connection as well? What is the encoding of the column / table? Collation is pretty uninteresting, look for encoding. Also when that data was inserted via a website (was it or not, please say), which encoding was the website?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment so I post this as an answer although I wouldn't really like to call it an answer.

I would locate a single string that you can use as test and then simply run a series of conversions to see if any one of them gets it right. There's a list of character sets the mbstring module supports [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php). So basically you'd do something like:

```
$string = "whatever"; // String you retrieve from the database.
$charSets = array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', ...); // Fill this array with the character sets.

foreach ($charSets as $cs) {
    print mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', $cs)."\n";
}
```

You could, and probably should use iconv() instead but I didn't have a list of supported character sets for that handy so I used mbstring as an example.

Comment: I used this code and entered all charsets supported by PHP. I couldn't find a solution, so I modified the code to try two, three and four charsets applied over each other. That didn't help either. Strange, strange …

Comment: Then I'd check if it can be a matter of little-endian vs. big-endian data. Not very likely but could be worth a try.